# What is the difference between the mitotic spindle and microtubules?

Tags: biochemistry, molecular-genetics, terminology, mitosis

In mitosis, I understand that the centromeres line up on the spindle. I also know that the centrioles form microtubles between the centromeres during mitosis in the metaphase.

But, are microtubles and spindles the same thing? Or do microtubles make up spindles?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Short answer**
The spindle is made up of microtubules

**Background**
From [Nature](http://www.nature.com/scitable/definition/spindle-fibers-304):

[image]

> Spindle fibers form a protein structure that divides the genetic
>   material in a cell. [...] At the beginning of nuclear division, two
>   wheel-shaped protein structures called centrioles position themselves
>   at opposite ends of the cell forming cell poles. **Long protein fibers
>   called microtubules** extend from the centrioles in all possible
>   directions, forming what is called a **spindle**. Some of the
>   microtubules attach the poles to the chromosomes by connecting to
>   protein complexes called kinetochores. Kinetochores are protein
>   formations that develop on each chromosome around the centromere,
>   which is a region located near the middle of a chromosome. Other
>   microtubules bind to the chromosome arms or extend to the opposite end
>   of the cell. During the cell division phase called metaphase, the
>   microtubules pull the chromosomes back and forth until they align in a
>   plane along the equator of the cell, which is called the equatorial
>   plane.